# There is this guy I know who looks just like him

Tags: syntactic-analysis

There is this guy I know who looks just like him.

I have seen this sentence from a text book.
When I saw it, to begin with I thought 3 sentences.

> (A) There is this guy.​

> (B) I know this guy​

> (C) This guy looks just like him.​

and then I thought;

> (B) + (C) = I know (that) this guy looks just like him. : I'd like to call it (D)

and then I thought;

> (D) + (A) = There is this guy who looks just like him (that) I know. : I'd like to call it (F).

Thus (F) was what I thought original sentence might have been.
But it is not. I am wrong, because the text book says "There is this guy I know who looks just like him.". Hmm.....My sentence is (F) wrong?

Comment: Welcome to ELU!  What is your question?  You start by giving us a sentence but then later you say you think F is the original sentence. Surely the original sentence is the one in the title (?)  Please tell us exactly what the question is that you are trying to answer.

Comment: Hi I thought (F) sentence is a result from combining (A), (B), and (C). "There is this guy who looks just like him (that) I know." However, the text book says "There is this guy I know who looks just like him.". Now I am curious whether (F) is wrong or not.

Comment: Your sentence is exactly like saying I know someone who looks like him.

Comment: (F) is ok- it works.  But the sentence in the title flows better and is more succinct.

Answer (score 0):

F is the correct interpretation - 'There is a guy, [whom] I know, who looks like him.'

To get the D meaning it would have to be 'There is a guy who, I know, looks like him.'

(Yes, I know some folks will tell me off for using *whom*!)

Comment: Hi, I don't still understand your last sentence - (Yes, I know some folks will tell me off for using whom!). Could you elaborate on it in detail, please?

Comment: Also, There is this guy who looks just like him (that) I know. : I'd like to call it (F). I didn't mean (that-can be elided) is what you said it was. I mean it is relative pronoun. I guess you are saying embedded clause , (whom-can be elided) I know,

Comment: It was a humorous comment directed to some of the other people who post on this forum. It's correct to use _whom_ for the object of a verb, but some say that the rule is very outdated and we should only use _who_.

Comment: I don't understand your second comment. Your sentence F means that you know the guy,   but D means that you know the fact that he looks like someone else.

Comment: Thank you. Hmm, so "There is this guy I know who looks just like him" by textbook and  "There is this guy who looks just like him, whom I know. "

Comment: Plus, There is this guy who looks just like him (that) I know. <-- This is wrong, right? "(that) I know" does not refer to "this guy"?? Because they are separated too much.

Comment: _There is this guy who looks just like him, who[m] I know_ and _that I know_ are both confusing sentences for just that reason.

Comment: In practice, you can move parts of sentences around in strange ways, including separating adjectival clauses from the noun they modify, and people will still infer the likely meaning. It's bad style, but common to see.